# Hi when I upload the image in my app and when i try to pinch and zoom in it zooms pass the edge and vertices of the image? Whats wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.10

So my App is meant to display a live video feed on an app and then gives u options to snap a picture, upload an image and return to the camera feed. The video feed works fin and i can pinch my screen to zoom in and swipe to move in that direction without exceeding the image edge and vertices. But when i try that with uploading an image a problem occurs i can zoom past the edge and vertices and swipe pass after zooming in.

Ive tried using Chat gpt to fix it but it dosent know how. Im quite stuck can anyone give me a hand?

```
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics.transformation import Matrix
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.utils import platform
import threading
import os
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserIconView
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')  # disable multi-touch


class KivyCamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, capture, fps, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = capture
        self.fps = fps
        self.event = None
        self.allow_stretch = True  # Allow the image to be resized.
        self.keep_ratio = False  # Allow the aspect ratio to be changed.
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        if self.event is None:
            self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / self.fps)

    def stop(self):
        if self.event is not None:
            self.event.cancel()
            self.event = None

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            # convert it to texture
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            # display image from the texture
            self.texture = image_texture


class CustomScatter(Scatter):
    def on_transform_with_touch(self, touch):
        # Override Scatter's method to prevent it from changing the widget order
        pass

class ScatterImage(Scatter, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScatterImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.allow_stretch = True
        self.keep_ratio = False
        self.do_translation = True
        self.do_rotation = False
        self.do_scale = True

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return super(ScatterImage, self).on_touch_down(touch)
        return False

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return super(ScatterImage, self).on_touch_move(touch)
        return False

    def on_transform_with_touch(self, touch):
        min_scale = max(self.parent.width / self.width, self.parent.height / self.height)

        if self.scale < min_scale:
            self.scale = min_scale
        elif self.scale > 3 * min_scale:  # limiting the max zoom to 3 times the min_scale
            self.scale = 3 * min_scale

        # To ensure that the image never goes out of the screen
        if self.x > 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif self.right < self.parent.width:
            self.x = self.parent.width - self.width * self.scale

        if self.y > 0:
            self.y = 0
        elif self.top < self.parent.height:
            self.y = self.parent.height - self.height * self.scale
    def on_size(self, *args):
        if self.parent is not None:
            self.width = self.parent.width
            self.height = self.parent.height


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = FloatLayout()
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.my_camera = KivyCamera(capture=self.capture, fps=30)
        self.scatter = CustomScatter(do_rotation=False, do_translation=True)  # Use CustomScatter
        self.scatter.size = root.size
        self.scatter.pos = root.pos
        self.scatter.add_widget(self.my_camera)
        
        relative_layout_video = RelativeLayout()
        relative_layout_video.add_widget(self.scatter)

        self.capture_button = Button(text='Capture', size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 50), pos_hint={'x': 0, 'y': 0})
        self.capture_button.bind(on_release=self.capture_screenshot)
        
        relative_layout_button = RelativeLayout()
        relative_layout_button.add_widget(self.capture_button)

        root.add_widget(relative_layout_video)
        root.add_widget(relative_layout_button)
        self.upload_button = Button(text='Upload', size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 50), pos_hint={'x': 0.2, 'y': 0})
        self.upload_button.bind(on_release=self.open_filechooser)

        relative_layout_button.add_widget(self.upload_button)

        self.switch_button = Button(text='Live Video', size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 50), pos_hint={'x': 0.4, 'y': 0})
        self.switch_button.bind(on_release=self.switch_to_live_video)
        relative_layout_button.add_widget(self.switch_button)

        

        def update_scatter_size(instance, value):
            self.scatter.size = value
            self.my_camera.size = value

        root.bind(size=update_scatter_size)

        def on_touch_down(window, touch):
            if touch.is_double_tap:
                self.scatter.scale = 1
                self.scatter.pos = root.pos
            return False  # Continue processing the event.

        def on_touch_move(window, touch):
            if len(touch.grab_list) > 0:
                if touch.is_mouse_scrolling:
                    if touch.button == 'scrolldown':
                        if self.scatter.scale > 1:
                            self.scatter.scale = self.scatter.scale * 0.9
                    elif touch.button == 'scrollup':
                        self.scatter.scale = self.scatter.scale * 1.1
                elif touch.grab_current is self.scatter:
                    if len(self.scatter._touches) == 1:  # One finger swipe.
                        touch1 = self.scatter._touches[0]
                        new_x = self.scatter.x + touch1.dx
                        new_y = self.scatter.y + touch1.dy
                        min_x = min(0, self.scatter.width - self.scatter.width * self.scatter.scale)
                        max_y = max(0, self.scatter.height - self.scatter.height * self.scatter.scale)
                        new_x = min(max(new_x, min_x), 0)
                        new_y = max(min(new_y, max_y), 0)
                        self.scatter.pos = (new_x, new_y)
                    elif len(self.scatter._touches) == 2:  # Two finger pinch.
                        # Use distance between the two touches as the scale.
                        touch1, touch2 = self.scatter._touches
                        self.scatter.center = ((touch1.x + touch2.x) / 2, (touch1.y + touch2.y) / 2)  # Center at the midpoint of the two touches.
                        self.scatter.scale = ((touch1.dx**2 + touch1.dy**2)**0.5 +
                                            (touch2.dx**2 + touch2.dy**2)**0.5) / self.scatter.width
                        if self.scatter.scale < 1:
                            self.scatter.scale = 1
            return True  # Return True to indicate that the event was handled.

        def on_transform_with_touch(scatter, touch):
            # Limit the panning to the edge of the image.
            if scatter.x > 0:
                scatter.x = 0
            if scatter.y > 0:
                scatter.y = 0
            if scatter.right < scatter.width:  # use scatter.right which gives the x-coordinate of the right side of the scatter widget
                scatter.right = scatter.width
            if scatter.top < scatter.height:  # use scatter.top which gives the y-coordinate of the top side of the scatter widget
                scatter.top = scatter.height

            # Prevent zooming out past the original size
            if scatter.scale < 1:
                scatter.scale = 1

        Window.bind(on_touch_down=on_touch_down)
        Window.bind(on_touch_move=on_touch_move)
        self.scatter.bind(on_transform_with_touch=on_transform_with_touch)
        
        return root


    def capture_screenshot(self, *args):
        print("Screenshot Captured!")
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
            filename = f'screenshot_{timestamp}.png'
            is_written = cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
            print(f'Screenshot saved as {filename}') if is_written else print('Error in saving screenshot')

    def open_filechooser(self, *args):
        content = FileChooserIconView(path=os.getcwd())
        content.bind(on_submit=self.load_image)
        popup = Popup(title="Select an image", content=content, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        popup.open()

    def load_image(self, instance, value, *args):
        self.my_camera.stop()
        self.capture.release()
        self.scatter.clear_widgets()  # clear all child widgets
        scatter_image = ScatterImage(source=value[0], size=self.scatter.size, pos=self.scatter.pos)
        self.scatter.add_widget(scatter_image)


    def switch_to_live_video(self, *args):
        self.scatter.clear_widgets()  # clear all child widgets
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.my_camera = KivyCamera(capture=self.capture, fps=30)
        self.my_camera.allow_stretch = True  # Enable stretching the video to fill the screen
        self.my_camera.keep_ratio = False  # Disable maintaining the aspect ratio
        self.my_camera.size = self.scatter.size  # Set the size of the camera to match the scatter widget
        self.my_camera.pos = self.scatter.pos  # Set the position of the camera to match the scatter widget
        self.scatter.add_widget(self.my_camera)
        self.my_camera.start()
        self.scatter.scale = 1
        self.scatter.pos = self.root.pos




if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```